# Как создать связку VPN -> Tor -> Internet, в качестве Socks proxy на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, vpn, tor

В сети много мануалов как сделать связку Tor -> VPN -> Internet, но обратного я не нашёл.

В данный момент на виртуалке установлен Ubuntu server 18.04 + Tor + OpenVPN, после запуска Tor проверяю его работу: `curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 ipinfo.io/ip`, всё работает как нужно, но мне нужно чтобы Tor не использовал мой IP, а IP VPN, но при этом остальной трафик шёл напрямую без Tor и VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Остановился на связке Tor -> Internet, Tor в моем случае используется как socks5 proxy, и как показала практика VPN будет избыточен.